# is there a way to add the tooltip for every road in folium?

Tags: python, dictionary, folium

I'm making a map of the different bus routes in my city, I have the [lat,lon] of every station and point but the problem is that I can't seem to find a way to name the routes that I created.

Here's the code:

```
>df = pd.read_excel (r'Bus.xlsx')
>points= pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(len(df)), columns=np.arange(2))
>points.columns = ["Latitude", "Longitude"]
>names = list()
>for i in range(len(df)):
>    points.iloc[i,1] = df.iloc[i,3]
>    points.iloc[i,0] = df.iloc[i,4]
>    names.append(df.iloc[i,2])

>folium.PolyLine(points, color="red", weight=2.5, opacity=1, tooltip=names).add_to(my_map)
```

but when I open the map, the name that appears when I hover the mouse is the whole list as in ['xxx','yyyy','zzzz']

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

(Just cleaning up your prep:)

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'Bus.xlsx')

points = df.iloc[:,[3,4]]
points.columns = ["Latitude", "Longitude"]

names = df.iloc[:,2].to_list()
```

This is the problematic line, as I understand it.

```
folium.PolyLine(points, color="red", weight=2.5, opacity=1, tooltip=names).add_to(my_map)
```

If I understand correctly, you're passing a table of points and drawing **one** polyline -- and then the tooltip for this line is your list of names.  I believe you instead need to generate a list/DataFrame of *pairs of points* and corresponding names for *route between pairs of points*, and then for each *pair*, add that as a `PolyLine` to your map.